# What technology is needed to create a live video streaming service?

Tags: web-services

I am curious as to what technology is needed to create a service such as stageit.com and livestream.com. What hardware and software is involved, besides a camera and microphone, from the broadcaster's computer to a viewer's computer?

Answer (score 5):

I've been in the streaming media business for 5 years now, and I can confirm you the best choice is [Wowza Media Server](http://www.wowza.com). It was created by former Adode (flash server) employees.

Just check their [references](http://www.wowza.com/customers), they just speak for them.

One of the huge advantage of Wowza is its [extensibility](http://www.wowza.com/media-server/developers). You can customize it using Java.

Comment: Thank you very much! Will research more on your suggestion :)

Answer (score 4):

There are several streaming servers.
Apart from the well-known Wowza, Helix, PVNS, QTSS there are many free solutions (see below some sorted in order of ease of usage):

1. Feng/Lscube - http://lscube.org/howto/live_streaming_flux here is a  simple tutorial how to use it
2. Red5 - http://trac.red5.org/wiki/Documentation#Tutorials
3. Darwin streaming server - http://dss.macosforge.org/
4. Xuggler - http://www.xuggle.com/

Comment: Thank you very much! Will research more on your suggestions :)